# Undefined reference to all my functions C++ I think it may be because of my makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, undefined-reference

I have a header file **cerealmanager.h** and a main file called **cerealmanager.cpp** and a file called **project2.cpp**, which just has catch 2 tests.

Whenever I run my code with the makefile it says that all of my functions are `undefined` (undefined reference CerealManager::(functionname).

How do I solve this issue?

#### makefile

```
CPP_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror

# uncomment for Linux/Mac OS X
#RM = rm -f

# uncomment for Windows (make sure MinGW/MSYS are installed!)
RM = del

project2.exe: project2.cpp cerealmanager.o
  g++ $(CPP_FLAGS) project2.cpp cerealmanager.o -o project2.exe

cerealmanager.o: cerealmanager.h cerealmanager.cpp
  g++ $(CPP_FLAGS) -c cerealmanager.cpp -o cerealmanager.o

clean:
  $(RM) *.o

cleanall: clean
  $(RM) *.exe
```

Comment: The rules applicable here to this type of question require that you reduce the problem to a simple compact case which still demonstrates the issue and post the entirety of the code and compiler error output.  Likely in the course of doing that, you'll identify the issue yourself.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Is it possible for you to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it’s maybe due to the Makefile. But I think this is not the case.

You can read more regarding “undefined reference to” [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/latedev.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/common-c-error-messages-2-unresolved-reference/amp/)

Hope this will help you.